# Two joins with PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add new column from another table, now i have query:

```
SELECT
Id    
,Symbol
,Nazwa
,isnull([100000],0) AS [Magazyn 1]
,isnull([100005],0) AS [Magazyn 2]
,isnull([100006],0) AS [Magazyn 3]
,isnull([100000],0)+isnull([100005],0)+isnull([100006],0) Razem

FROM (
SELECT

ASO.id
,ASO.Symbol
,ASO.Nazwa
,STANY.IloscDostepna
,STANY.Magazyn_ID

FROM
ModelDanychContainer.Asortymenty ASO

LEFT JOIN ModelDanychContainer.StanyMagazynowe STANY ON STANY.Asortyment_ID 
= ASO.ID) AS sc

PIVOT
(
SUM(IloscDostepna) FOR Magazyn_ID IN ([100000],[100005],[100006])
) AS pv
```

And i want to add column from table:

```
JOIN ModelDanychContainer.GrupyAsortymentu GRUPY ON GRUPY.ID = ASO.GRUPA_ID
```

When i try to do this like below i get errors:

> 4104 the multi-part identifier GRUPY.NAZWA could not be bound
>
> 8156 The column NAZWA was specified multiple times for 'sc'
>
> 8156 The column NAZWA was specified multiple times for 'pv'

```
SELECT
Id    
,Symbol
,GRUPY.Nazwa
,Nazwa
,isnull([100000],0) AS [Magazyn 1]
,isnull([100005],0) AS [Magazyn 2]
,isnull([100006],0) AS [Magazyn 3]
,isnull([100000],0)+isnull([100005],0)+isnull([100006],0) Razem

 FROM (
 SELECT
ASO.id
,ASO.Symbol
,ASO.Nazwa
,GRUPY.Nazwa
,STANY.IloscDostepna
,STANY.Magazyn_ID

FROM
ModelDanychContainer.Asortymenty ASO

LEFT JOIN ModelDanychContainer.StanyMagazynowe STANY ON STANY.Asortyment_ID 
= ASO.ID

JOIN ModelDanychContainer.GrupyAsortymentu GRUPY ON GRUPY.ID = ASO.GRUPA_ID) 
AS sc

PIVOT
(
SUM(IloscDostepna) FOR Magazyn_ID IN ([100000],[100005],[100006])
) AS pv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT
    Id    
    ,Symbol
    ,GroupyNazwa
    ,AsoNazwa
    ,isnull([100000],0) AS [Magazyn 1]
    ,isnull([100005],0) AS [Magazyn 2]
    ,isnull([100006],0) AS [Magazyn 3]
    ,isnull([100000],0)+isnull([100005],0)+isnull([100006],0) Razem
FROM (
        SELECT
            ASO.id
            ,ASO.Symbol
            ,ASO.Nazwa AS AsoNazwa
            ,GRUPY.Nazwa AS GroupyNazwa
            ,STANY.IloscDostepna
            ,STANY.Magazyn_ID
        FROM
            ModelDanychContainer.Asortymenty ASO
            LEFT JOIN ModelDanychContainer.StanyMagazynowe STANY ON STANY.Asortyment_ID = ASO.ID
            JOIN ModelDanychContainer.GrupyAsortymentu GRUPY ON GRUPY.ID = ASO.GRUPA_ID
    ) 
        AS sc

    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(IloscDostepna) FOR Magazyn_ID IN ([100000],[100005],[100006])
    ) AS pv
```

The problem is that the subquery had 2 columns with the same alias "Nazwa" which were `ASO.Nazwa` and `GRUPY.Nazwa`.